# Каким является самым оптимальным значением setfetchsize для postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql

Каким является самым оптимальным значением setfetchsize для postgres? Есть таблица на несколько миллионов строк, но не могу нагуглить сколько установить для этого метода. Подскажите кому не сложно.

Comment: оптимального значения нет. все зависит в основном от вашего запроса, т.е. чем ближе угадаете количество возвращаемых записей, тем меньше раз клиент будет бегать на сервер. если же задать слишком большое значение, то могут возникнуть проблемы с памятью https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552902/jdbc-hibernate-fetch-size-and-memory-issues